# Error when opening IPython notebook list using EIN

Tags: ipython, ein, json

I am not entirely sure where to post this question (here, stackoverflow....), but I am sure some `emacs` experts will be able to help me here. This question is also posted here https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/158 , so the reader can go there for some more details.

Recently I managed to set `IPython` in `emacs` and I have been so far happily coding using the "interplay" of the two.

I now need to share some code and the `IPython Notebook` seems like the best tool to do so. Therefore, I have been using `IPython` the "normal" way until I recently learned that IPython can also be set up on emacs https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook .

I decided to give it a go and install all the requirements: `websocket`, `request` etc.

However, now, every time I try to run `Emacs IPython Notebook` via `M-x ein:notebooklist-open` I find the following error messages:

`Contacting host: 127.0.0.1:8961
ein: [error] QUERY-AJAX--PARSE-DATA: error from parser ein:json-read
error in process filter: eq: JSON readtable error
error in process filter: JSON readtable error
ein: [error] QUERY-AJAX--PARSE-DATA: error from parser ein:json-read
Error running timerein:query-ajax-timeout-callback': (json-readtable-error)`

The relevant section of my `.emacs` file looks like this (I am sure that most of it is not needed, but I have gone through a lot of iterations):

`;;Ipython Notebook
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/elpa/request-0.2.0/")
(require 'request)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/elpa/helm-1.6.7/")
(require 'helm)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/elpa/company-0.8.9/")
(autoload 'company-mode "company" nil t)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-0.5.2/")
(require 'popup)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/elpa/websocket-1.3/")
(require 'websocket)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-0.2.0/")
(require 'ein)
(require 'cc-mode)
;;(setq ein:use-auto-complete t)
;; Or, to enable "superpack" (a little bit hacky improvements):
(setq ein:use-auto-complete-superpack t)
(setq ein:use-smartrep t)`

more details about my `System Info` can be found here https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/158

To my understanding the problem seems to be related to request and the fact that despite the `(require 'request)` the `request.el` seems to either not having been loaded or not being visible to `ein`.

At this stage I do not know what to edit/install to make it work so I can use the notebook in emacs like is shown here https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/wiki/Screenshots .

I also found this [Emacs EIN vs IPython shell](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/428/emacs-ein-vs-ipython-shell) but seems not to solve my problem.

Comment: How did you install EIN? I found the tkf version to not support IPython 2.0. Melpa install upgraded me to a different version which does support IP2.0.

Comment: @mankoff: thanks for your comment. I used melpa, `package-install` and then `ein`. I do believe my problem is related to the `register` package, but I am not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emacs EIN vs IPython shell](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/428/emacs-ein-vs-ipython-shell)

Comment: Why do you do all those `(add-to-list 'load-path ...)`?  You should instead call `(package-initialize)` which will do that (and the corresponding `require` when needed) for you.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answers! I asked this question 2 years ago and I actually moved to sublime since then :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [current EIN](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) that took over. On Emacs 25, it works out of the box.

> ## Usage
>
> 1. Install from [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/)*.    For manual install, put Emacs lisp `ein*.el` files and Python file    `ein.py` in your load path. See
>      `online documentation`* for more    information.
> 2. Start the [`Jupyter notebook server`](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content-quickstart.html).
> 3. (Optional) Newer versions of Jupyter have token [authentication](http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/12/21/jupyter-notebook-4-3-1/)_ enabled by default so you will need to call `M-x ein:notebooklist-login` and enter the    token as the password.
> 4. Execute `M-x ein:notebooklist-open` to open notebook list.